# Redirect my subdomain to principal domain via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I created a Wordpress blog on http://staging.mydomain.com and now that the website is ready i want all the pages to point to http://www.mydomain.com . I configured Wordpress to do that,the problem is that Google already index http://staging.mydomain.com articles and i want the pages to redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/Name-of-the-article

I search around and found that I need to do a 301 redirection via a htaccess but I don't know what to write.

Thank you for taking the time to read my answer.

Comment: Do you have any control over the DNS of your domain? In that case you can use a CNAME record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.mydomain.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but this only redirect the homepage I want all the pages of staging to be redirect to www.

for example: http://staging.example.com/article-1 to become http://www.example.com/article-1

Comment: The rule is absolutely fine -- tested and working. Has to be something on your side. Try moving these rules to the top (above all other rewrite rules).